# change theme in app by downloading another apk file and getting resources from there

Tags: android

After scouring the internet for hours, I've posted this on SO.

Requirements:

My app will have a total of three themes for user to select from. (Free app)
User should download an apk from play store to get these three themes. (Paid apps)

After downloading the paid app the free app should allow user to set any of the three themes in the free app.

How to achieve this please guide me.

I've reached a dead end on this one but I see many apps have achieved this already but there is not guide available anywhere on the web.

Comment: Integrate the In App Purchase in the free app. Once user purchase then allow user to get these three themes..

Comment: @TGMCians: That is also another option I'm considering. But I'm still not sure how to get theme from the other app into the free app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing themed applications in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937279/writing-themed-applications-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4803631/858626) to [How to release application plugin using Android Market?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4803342/858626) 
will help you. It's not a complete guide but a fair starting point.

Basically you use `PackageManager.getResourcesForActivity` or `PackageManager.getResourcesForApplication` to retrieve resources from the other packages, and then use them as you would with an own resource. This other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11288147/858626) may complete the picture for you.

Answer (score 0):

After you get the .apk, you can read it as a zip and manually search your theme in the resources (res) or assets folder.

Comment: Won't there be permission issues to read apk of another package in linux kernel. Another complexity I see here is that how do i write the data into the free app permanently. The res folder can't be modified after installation, correct me if I'm wrong.