# making customized theme for android phone

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm a new mobile developer and i know how to put theme on an application i was able to make 2 mobile application as of now but i wanted to try to make a customized theme for phones. I'm wondering if anyone out there has idea on the following.

```
1.how to make a customized theme for phone.
2.what is the format of the theme.
3.is it possible to make it in eclipse.
4.what are the things needed to consider to make a theme for phone.
5.how to implement customized theme on phone.
6.available tutorial on making a customized phone theme.
```

Comment: Have you even searched?  There are a lot of examples of this, and this is something fundamental to the Android Framework.  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html is a good starting point.  There are a million tutorials, and examples.  This this is a bad question (too basic, and not any initiative to learn basic concepts - then ask specific coding questions).

Comment: This is also not a theme, but a custom Layout (these are different terms in Android).  You need to supply different Layouts for different screens (or write your layouts responsively, and use the same one everywhere).

Comment: @Booger  i am trying to achieve here is to change the theme of mobile itself and not the theme of an application i wanted to know if it is even possible like changing the theme of a personal computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change theme of a specific theme application like GO Launcher or aHome you can find a link on their site, see this question for more information [Themes in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613101/themes-in-android/2613581)

but you can also write your launcher application, if you want to do this, you can see this links: [Build An Application Launcher For Android](http://www.taywils.me/2011/07/05/buildanapplicationlauncherwithandroid.html)

But if you want to change theme of your application, so you can read these documents and tutorials:

1. [developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)
2. [Android Styles and Themes - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidStylesThemes/article.html)

Another way that i think you must know for building several themes is building an apk for every theme of your application, this solution make your app size smaller. like this function:

```
public static Resources getResource() {
        resourcePackageName = "com.mine.MyApp";
        PackageManager packageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();
        Resources resources = null, resources2 = null;
        try {
            resources = mContext.getResources();
            resources2 = packageManager
                    .getResourcesForApplication("com.mine.MyAppTheme");
            resourcePackageName = "com.mine.MyAppTheme";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ss", e.toString());
        }

        if (resources2 != null)
            mResource = resources2;
        else
            mResource = resources;
        return mResource;
    }
```

In this code, your app name is `com.mine.MyApp` and you have a app with all of resources in the `com.mine.MyApp` that is your theme, name of theme apk app is `com.mine.MyAppTheme`. you can use several apk as several theme. just put your resources on theme apk file. you can see this question:
 [Writing themed applications in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937279/writing-themed-applications-in-android)

Comment: these are awesome tutorials buddy i will try to make them out to see if i can make it work.what i wanted to do is to make or change the theme of the phone/mobile itself like changing the theme of the a personal computer is it applicable to mobile and how is it done.

Comment: if it's helpful for you, check it as true answer.

Comment: its helpful but it doesn't answer my problem it changes the them of an app what i want to change is the theme of the mobile itself.any idea on that matter?

Comment: i think you must read my answer again, i am talking about change theme of mobile. do you see this link? http://www.taywils.me/2011/07/05/buildanapplicationlauncherwithandroid.html You must make a launcher app.

Comment: have you tried the tutorial in there coz im having a few errors http://www.taywils.me/2011/07/05/buildanapplicationlauncherwithandroid.html